# NX Angular + Nest - Angular app is throwing an express error

Tags: angular, express, nest, nx-workspace

I've created an NX workspace with an angular app and a nest app, and when I run the angular app (with or without the nest app running), I get an error coming from express.  This is what I see in the browser:

```json
{"path":"/","name":"NotFoundException","message":"Cannot GET /","exception":{"response":{"statusCode":404,"message":"Cannot GET /","error":"Not Found"},"status":404,"message":"Cannot GET /","name":"NotFoundException"},"stack":"NotFoundException: Cannot GET /\n    at callback (/node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/routes-resolver.js:77:19)\n    at /node_modules/@nestjs/core/router/router-proxy.js:9:23\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at trim_prefix (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:323:13)\n    at /node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7\n    at Function.process_params (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:341:12)\n    at next (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)\n    at urlencodedParser (/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/urlencoded.js:91:7)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at trim_prefix (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:323:13)"}
```

I'm not sure why this is invoking express in any way.  Any ideas?